# Not able to do summation of values in each(FY) column of web table in selenium #java

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, html-table, ui-automation

I am trying to add each column's values(Values under FY header) and I tried all way to add the values but I am not getting any valid results.
Below is the latest one which I was trying and I am getting errors.

```
    WebElement table = driver.findElement(By.id("contentWrapper"));
    List<WebElement> rowsList = table.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='subrowstyl']"));
    int numRows = rowsList.size();
    
    System.out.println("Total number of rows= " + numRows);
            
    if (leftColumnheaderBSData.size() == rightColumnheaderBSData.size()) {

        System.out.println("-----------------------------------------------------------------------------");
        System.out.print(new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(10))
                .until(ExpectedConditions
                        .visibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.xpath("//div[text()[contains(.,'FY')]]")))
                .stream().map(element -> element.getText().toString() + "  :  ").collect(Collectors.toList()));
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("-----------------------------------------------------------------------------");
        
        for(WebElement leftHeader : leftColumnheaderBSData)
        {    
            List<WebElement> rows = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='subrowstyl']"));
             int rowsize=rows.size();
                int sum = 0;
                List<Integer> values = new ArrayList<Integer>();
                for(int i=1; i< rowsize; i++){
            {
                String sCellValue = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@style='padding-left: 1vw; width: 50%;']//span[@container='body']")).getText().toString();
                System.out.println(values.add(Integer.parseInt(sCellValue)));
              
                
            }
                }
                for (int i: values) {
                    sum += i;
                }
                System.out.println("Sum: " + sum);
        }
        
    }
```

**Can some one Please suggest how to achieve this target**

[image]

[image]

Comment: what kind of errors? pls, provide more (and better) info

Comment: also, why you're trying to fetch text of the div element? the value is in span element

Comment: Thanks, I corrected this part but still same error. I have attached error screen shot

Comment: you have to parse the string into double using correct format

Comment: After changing to double still I am getting NumberFormat .Exception.java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "76,837,629.00"

Comment: Double dvalue=Double.parseDouble( sCellValue.replace(",","")) ; This worked. Thanks for your suggestion . @Marek